# How can I get the page arguments of an .asp in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vbscript

Is it possible to get some page arguments from an asp file in a js function ?
I'm kind of new to these technologies, and I was asked to migrate some old code, but I'm not sure if it's possible.
Here is what I got so far :

I have a file CommentsPage.aspx which contains a call to a conversation.html which contains a button :

```
<button type="button" class="plm-ImportMsgFiles-button btn bg-transparent border-0 p-0 ml-1"
                title="ImportMsgFiles">
      <svg class="plm-icon-sm plm-icon-green">
        <use href="#do-remove-disc"></use>
      </svg>
</button>
```

This button executes some js :

```
$(".plm-conversation").on("click", ".plm-ImportMsgFiles-button", function() {
    // import msg file.
    var commentPartGuid = $(this).closest(".plm-conversation-item")
            .attr("data-plm-partguid");
    ImportMsgFiles(commentPartGuid);
});
```

That js will call a CSIcmdImportMsgFiles.asp which contains some important calls to some code in C#. That same js code used to get some page arguments from this asp, but it's not working anymore. Here is the call to the asp and the call for the page arguments as it was :
The parameters are strCommandId for the command to execute in the asp, strCommandUrl for the url of the asp, callbackFunction for the function to execute at the end, and strFrameName is left blank.

```
    Namespace.SendCommandImport = function (strCommandId, strCommandUrl, callbackFunction, strFrameName) {
    if (!strFrameName) {
        strFrameName = "oNamespaceCommandFrame";
    }
    if (callbackFunction) {
        if (Namespace.RegisterCommand(strCommandId, callbackFunction)) {
            var objCommandFrame = window.frames[strFrameName];

            if (!objCommandFrame) {
                Namespace.CreateFrameImport(strFrameName);
                objCommandFrame = window.frames[strFrameName];
            }
            if (objCommandFrame) {
                _isNamespaceCommandReady = true;
                objCommandFrame.location.replace("Blank.asp");
                objCommandFrame.location.replace(strCommandUrl);
            }
        }
    }
}

Namespace.CreateFrameImport = function (strFrameName) {
    var objCommandFrame = null;
    if (_Browser.IsFirefox || _Browser.IsIE10OrLater || _Browser.IsChrome) {
        objCommandFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
        objCommandFrame.setAttribute("name", strFrameName);
    }
    else
        objCommandFrame = document.createElement("<iframe name=\"" + strFrameName + "\" ></iframe>");
    objCommandFrame.setAttribute("id", strFrameName);
    objCommandFrame.setAttribute("src", "Blank.asp");
    document.body.appendChild(objCommandFrame);
    objCommandFrame.style.display = "none";
    var loadHandler = function () {
        Namespace.CommandDoneImport(strFrameName);
    };
    if (objCommandFrame.addEventListener) {
        objCommandFrame.addEventListener("load", loadHandler, false);
    } else {
        objCommandFrame.attachEvent("onload", loadHandler);
    }
}

Namespace.CommandDoneImport = function (strFrameName) {
    var objCommandFrame = window.frames[strFrameName];
    if (objCommandFrame != null) {
        var str_location = objCommandFrame.location.toString();
        if ((_isNamespaceCommandReady) && (str_location.indexOf("Blank.asp") < 0)) // Is there a command?
        {
            _isNamespaceCommandReady = false;

            var str_command_id = objCommandFrame.window.GetCommandId();
            var str_status = objCommandFrame.window.GetCommandStatus();
            if (_NamespaceCommands != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < _NamespaceCommands.length; i++) {
                    var command = _NamespaceCommands[i];
                    if (command != null) {
                        if (command[0] == str_command_id) {
                            command[1](str_command_id, str_status, objCommandFrame);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i execute this code the methods objCommandFrame.window.GetCommandId() and objCommandFrame.window.GetCommandStatus() are not recognized as functions. They are both defined in CSIcmdImportMsgFiles.asp like so :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _strCommandId = "<%=strCommandId%>";
    function GetCommandId() { return _strCommandId; }
</script>
```

With strCommandId being defined in the asp as dim strCommandId.

I will gladly provide more information as I am stuck on this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check if `str_location` in `CommandDoneImport` has `CSIcmdImportMsgFiles.asp` before calling the function inside that page.

Comment: Hi, the str_location has the CSIcmdImportMsgFiles.asp

Comment: ok. You could try calling the function directly from the frame? `objCommandFrame.GetCommandId()` or using the content window `objCommandFrame.contentWindow.GetCommandId()` ?

Comment: Calling directly from the frame doesn't work, and the contentWindow is undefined.

Comment: No more ideas. Sorry..